# Jmeter and DFE extensions

Tags: plugins, jmeter, loadrunner, data-transform

I have a project, where we are using LoadRunner and an DFE extension.
My question is it possible to migrate the project from LR to jMeter, without changing the DFE extension.
In general what it does is to get the request encrypt it and send it to the backend.
Identically, when the response is received, it decrypts it, so it becomes readable and parseble.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

JMeter knows nothing about [DFE](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60-12.63/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/r_web_data_format_extension_list.htm), if the response comes encrypted you will have to write the decryption logic yourself using i.s. [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Something like:

```
byte [] encryptedResponse = prev.getResponseData()
//the code to perform the decryption here
prev.setResponseData('decrypted response', 'UTF-8')
```

The code for decrypting the response will vary depending on the algorithm, you will need to either include it into your question to get a sample, so far I can only suggest getting familiarized with [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy) article

Answer (score 0):

DFE is a LoadRunner specific feature.  You will have to reconstruct the decode and encode in Jmeter.

I have a larger question, why is it that you are not achieving value out of LoadRunner?  The only reason why people switch performance tools is because of a question of value, either there is a problem measuring the value, or the value is so low in output that it is obvious to all.   Unless you address that value generation issue, then it will follow you to the new tool.

Value is generated in performance testing in analysis, where findings directly lead to recommendations to improve the performance of a piece of software either in client response, scalability, or often both.  Fix that problem first before you switch tools.   Until you generate a recommendation that improves performance you and your team are a cost that has no return associated with it.

If you choose to switch tools, then map out very clearly what your path to value is going to be.  Also, map out any changes in the cost (labor) associated with production of high quality data set for analysis purposes.   As Jmeter has a different feature set from LoadRunner, regarding monitoring and analysis, you will need to fill in those gaps in your switch with additional tools, and figure out how to bring both your response times and resource monitors together for analysis purposes.